# How can i build project with vue js & laravel in shared hosting?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.5, shared-hosting

I have integrated real chat system develop from VUE JS in my project developed in Laravel framework.

Comment: Build it locally and upload the distribution files

Answer (score 0):

All Vue components need to be compiled down to JavaScript locally. Laravel does that automatically out of the box and you end up with a single static asset app.js. You need to use npm -command to do that see Laravel documentation for details. Then you just deploy single static app.js with you code.